# After searching for a range how to put into variable

Tags: excel, vba

rng1 gives an errror, anyone know how to fix? Im trying to create a chart, but I need to find the second part of the range for the chart

```
Range("A1").Select

Cells.Find(What:="Sum(FRD End Analysis)", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Set rng1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:E2")



'Your data range for the chart
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:G1,rng1")

'Create a chart
  Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
```

Comment: To fix this, remove the `.Select`. However, your next statement will fail also, and for me it's not clear what you want to achieve with that.

Comment: create a chart with the data from that range....
Range("A1").Select
    
    Cells.Find(What:="Sum(FRD End Analysis)", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:E2").Select
   
       

    'Your data range for the chart
      Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:G1,rng1")
    
    'Create a chart
      Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart

Comment: Is `Sum(FRD End Analysis)` just text in a cell or the result of a formula or part of a formula?

Comment: its just text !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will fix the problem.  I'm guessing `rng1` was throwing an error because it wasn't finding *Sum(FRD End Analysis)* anywhere.  I'm not sure though as you don't say what error it's throwing.

It could be:  *variable not defined* (if you're using `Option Explicit`), or *Object variable or with block variable not set* because the `Find` statement didn't find anything, or a number of other things that I haven't thought of.

```
Sub Example()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim DisplayRange As Range

    'The code needs to know which sheet you're talking about.
    'Not designating the sheet means it will look at the currently active sheet.
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'The chart will be built to cover this range.
    Set DisplayRange = wrkSht.Range("D5:H20")

    'Try and find the cell and store it's reference in a range variable.
    'Note that it's using wrkSht variable to identify the sheet that cells are on.
    Set rFound = wrkSht.Cells.Find( _
        What:="SUM(FRD End Analysis)", _
        After:=wrkSht.Range("A1"), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    'If it hasn't been found then rFound will be nothing, otherwise it will not be nothing.
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

        'Here the cell 1 column to the right of rFound is considered to be cell "A1".
        'So if value is found in cell B2 then .Range("A1:E2") will reference cells C2:G3 (C2 is considered to be A1)
        Set rng1 = Union(wrkSht.Range("C1:G1"), rFound.Offset(, 1).Range("A1:E2"))

        'Create a chart container.
        Set cht = wrkSht.ChartObjects.Add _
            (DisplayRange.Left, DisplayRange.Top, DisplayRange.Width, DisplayRange.Height)

        'Build the chart within the chart container.
        With cht
            .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

            'Create the series from rng1.
            With .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Name = "First Row"
                .XValues = rng1.Rows(1)
                .Values = rng1.Rows(2)
            End With

            With .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Name = "Second Row"
                .XValues = rng1.Rows(1)
                .Values = rng1.Rows(3)
            End With

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```